# tell cin to stop reading at newline

Tags: c++

Suppose I want to read line a of integers from input like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5\n
```

I want cin to stop at '\n' character but cin doesn't seem to recognize it.

Below is what I used.

```
vector<int> getclause() {
  char c;
  vector<int> cl;

  while ( cin >> c && c!='\n') {    
    cl.push_back(c);
    cin>>c;
  }
  return cl;
}
```

How should I modify this so that cin stop when it see the '\n' character?

Comment: cin is whitespace delimited, so any whitespace (including `\n`) will be discarded. Thus, `c` will never be `\n`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use getline and istringstream:

```
#include <sstream>
/*....*/
vector<int> getclause() {
  char c;
  vector<int> cl;
  std::string line;
  std::getline(cin, line);
  std::istringstream iss(line);
  while ( iss >> c) {    
    cl.push_back(c);
  }
  return cl;
}
```

Comment: I am getting variable ‘std::istringstream iss’ has initializer but incomplete type

Comment: `getline` is also in namespace `std`, I think.

Comment: @Mark: That means you need `#include <sstream>`.  That message almost always means that a type has been declared but you're missing the actual definition.  In other words, you're missing a header.

Comment: @Drew Dormann fixed, i missed that one :D. Regarding the std::istringstream error, just include sstream as you can see in the example code.

Answer (score 4):

You can read all whitespace by setting [noskipws](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws) on the `istream`:

```
#include <ios>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

vector<int> getc() {
    char c;
    vector<int> cl;
    std::cin >> std::noskipws;
    while (std::cin >> c && c != '\n') {
        cl.push_back(c);
        std::cin >> c;
    }
    return cl;
}
```

If the standard input contains only a single line, you might as well construct the vector with the `istream_iterator`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using std::vector;

vector<int> getc() {
    // Replace char with int if you want to parse numbers instead of character codes
    vector<int> cl{
        std::istream_iterator<char>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<char>()
    };
    return cl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/getline/) method to first get the line, then use [istringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istringstream/) to get formatted input from the line.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::getline, this will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

`getchar()` is more efficient than `cin` when working with characters at this situation

I tried to do the same with a line of characters with unknown length and want it to stop at a newline but it has an infinite loop and haven't detect the newline, so I just used `getchar()` instead of `cin` and it works

Answer (score -2):

From this [link](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/73459/how-to-scan-integers-until-newline), it is quite simple to achieve this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int i=0,size,arr[10000];
    char temp; 
    do{
        scanf("%d%c", &arr[i], &temp); 
        i++; 
        } while(temp!= '\n');

    size=i; 
    for(i=0;i<size;i++){ 
        printf("%d ",arr[i]); 
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, C++, not C.