# Taking in a char vector from command line

Tags: c++, vector, command, char, endl

I'm taking a command and I want to store it as a vector of characters.

```
int main()
{
    vector<char> command;
    cout << "Reservations>>";
    char next;
    cin >> next;
    while (next !='\n'){
        command.push_back(next);
        cin >> next;
    }
    for(int i=0; i< command.size(); i++)
        cout << command[i];
}
```

But the while(next !='\n') is not working, as it keeps letting me type even though I've hit enter.

Comment: You could just input a string and make a vector from it.

Comment: Why not simply use: `std::vector<std::string>;`??

Comment: `std::cin` uses the enter key as a input delimiter, I expect it would not make it to the inputted character.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765462/how-to-cin-space-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673708/tell-cin-to-stop-reading-at-newline

Comment: @WillNasby check the links posted by jogojapan

Comment: @WillNasby. Firstly, please never change a question so it includes the answers given, only to ask a follow-up question. Follow-up questions, if necessary, should be _separate_ questions, or possibly be handled in the comments to an accepted answer. Secondly: have you actually looked at the links I posted? They tell you anything you need to know about how to stop `std::cin` ignoring whitespace.

Comment: Sorry, I'm clearly new here, I'll delete the 2nd part. I got my answer from your 2nd link so I just assumed your first was a similar solution, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I would use this:

```
cout << "Reservations>>";
string str;
getline (std::cin, str);
vector<char> command(str.begin(), str.end());
```

`getline` as a default uses `\r` and `\n` as a delimiters, compared with `cin` which also use space. `std::string` is the most common `char` container, so I'm sure you don't need to convert it into `vector`, but I added fastest way, how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Get input into a string then iterator it? or just use std::string to store command?

```
int main()
{
  cout << "Reservations>>";
  std::string command;
  cin >> command;  
  std::cout << command << std::endl;

  return (0);
}
```

I am not sure why you use std::vector but below sample should work:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<char> command;
  cout << "Reservations>>";
  std::string next;
  cin >> next;    
  for(size_t i = 0; i < next.size(); i++)
  {
    command.push_back(next.at(i));
  }

  for(int i=0; i< command.size(); i++)
  {
      cout << command[i];
  }

  return (0);
}
```