# How to take input to an array with unknown number of elements?

Tags: c++, arrays

```
int n = 10;
int a[n];  
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    cin >> a[i];
}
```

This is how I input array when we know the size of `n`. But when we don't know the size of `n` and we have to take input in an array and stop taking inputs when there is a new line. How can we do that in C++?

Comment: Use a `std::vector` rather than a fixed-size array.

Comment: There is no such thing as an "_array of unknown size_". To read unknown number of elements, consider using `std::vector`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::vector<int>` is what you need. Think of it as an array of dynamic size.

you can add elements to a vector by using `.push_back()`

see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: okay, but when I use vector<int> and push_back(), when will it stop taking input?

Comment: @sunidhichaudhary [tell cin to stop reading at newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673708/tell-cin-to-stop-reading-at-newline)

Comment: @sunidhichaudhary you could use special input for breaking the loop (e.g -1)

Answer (score 1):

To stop taking input you need to use EOF Concept. i.e. End of File. Place the cin in a while loop.
Something like this -

```
while (cin >> n)
{
  a.push_back(n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need a vector of type `string` unless you are using `stoi();`
So basically something like the code below.

```
int n = 10;
vector<string> a; 
string temp; 

while(cin>>temp)
{
   a.push_back(temp);
}
```

or

```
vector<int> a; 
while(cin>>temp)
    {
       a.push_back(stoi(temp));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So this prevents you from doing error checking, but at least for my toy projects is to use [`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) with an [`istream_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) So something like this:

```
const vector<int> a{ istream_iterator<int>{ cin }, istream_iterator<int>{} }
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/eyrJAp)