# Making text file, typing string by string

Tags: c++, file

I want to make text file, filling him string by string, until empty string. But, somehow I have infinite input, what conidition need I make to escape infinite loop?

Here is my code:

```
  fstream f;
f.open("text1.txt", ios::out);
bool flag = false;
while (!flag) {
    char buf[50];
    cin >> buf;
    if (strlen(buf)!=0 )
        f<<buf<<endl;
    else {
        f.close();
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tell cin to stop reading at newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673708/tell-cin-to-stop-reading-at-newline)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `cin >> buf` you are reading one word at a time. It's easier to use [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead:

```
fstream f;
f.open("text1.txt", ios::out);
bool flag = false;
while (!flag) {
    string str;
    getline(cin, str);
    if (cin && !str.empty())
        f<<str<<endl;
    else {
        f.close();
        flag = true;
    }
}
```

If you are forced to use fixed buffer, you need to search for `\n\n` occurrence in a data. `\n` is a new line symbol in C++.

Comment: My complier somehow says that getline is undefined, a f<<buf<<endl; must be changed to f<<str<<endl?

Comment: @Tovarisch, `std::getline` and `std::string` are defined in `<string>` header. You are right about using `str` instead of `buf` in output.

Comment: So there getline cant be used with char [ ]?

Comment: @Tovarisch, there is a method [`std::basic_istream::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline) that can be used with char array like that `cin.getline(buf, buf_size)`. It will read until new line but no more than `buf_size` chars.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate *while* loop until end of file.

```
fstream f;
f.open("text1.txt", ios::out);
char buf[50];

while (cin >> buf)    // it becomes false when end of file reach. You can test it from keyboard by Ctrl+Z and then Enter
{
    f<<buf<<endl;
}
f.close();
```